# How to disable Scala warning "The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time"

Tags: scala, warnings, compiler-warnings

I understand what the warning "The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time" means (final case class is missing its "outer" pointer if it is not used in the class itself). Still, I find this warning extremely annoying, as it is displayed even when I am not even matching against the type, like in the code below:

```
object X {
  class B {
    final case class A(a: Int)
  }

  def main(arg: Array[String]) = {

  }
}
```

How can I disable this warning, other than making the `case class` not `final`? Using `@unchecked` before the `case class` definition does not help.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Which Scala version?

Comment: Scastie and local SBT, Scala 2.11.12,  2.12.10 and 2.13.1 (I did not test any other)

Comment: That is weird. I am sure I have many of these on my projects and have never see the issue. Also, if you turn off the **worksheet** mode of Scastie the warning fades. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/105BCoLsSyyCyekjjGZRDg/2 so it seems like a problem with the REPL?

Comment: I see it in my project as well, and in other projects as well. I have just mentioned Scastie because it makes easy for anyone to test. I think I have never seen a `final case class` which would not produce this warning.

Comment: But did you checked my Scastie? I see no warning, but if I turn on the worksheet mode the warning appears. Also, I always have fatal warnings and my projects compile just fine. There must be something which we are missing to make this completely reproducible. Maybe some other compiler warning?

Comment: Once I add one more encapsulation level, the warning is back: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ev1JC24EQN6FsCWcv1UqZw

Comment: if changing `B` from a **class** to an **object** the warning goes away. Now, with a **class** the warning makes sense, since now `A` is path-dependent type.

Comment: It makes sense and I understand what it means, but I am never ever matching against the type, which is why I would like to disable the warning somehow.

Comment: I believe it makes sense if you pattern match on it. Anyways, I do not know how to disable the warning. Hope someone else may help you.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps as a workaround we could make case class in effect final by making the constructor private

```
class B {
  case class X private (s: String)
}
```

which prevents inheritance

```
class C extends X("") // Error
```

whilst still allowing construction due to public `apply` in the companion

```
(new B).X("")         // OK
```

The bug does not seem to be present in [dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/3652#issuecomment-350576698) so once Scala 3 is released it should be possible to revert to final case class (with perhaps regex replacement).